# dplyr: summarize(first(...)) returns column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use summarize to get the first result for each group, but it returns the column header instead:

(`get_table` is a custom function that gets a data table from a Postgres db)

```
require(dplyr)
require(RPostgres)

tbl <- get_table(my_server, my_table) %>%
  select(column_a, column_b) %>%
  group_by(column_a) %>%
  summarize(first_b = first(column_b))
```

The result looks like

```
a first_b
1 "column_b"
2 "column_b"
3 "column_b"
```

If I use `dplyr::collect()` before `summarize()` I get the desired result but this really slows down performance.
Any ideas how I can `summarize` without using `collect` first?

Comment: FYI I've reproduced this on another PostgresDB. What a strange behavior. (And it has a similar behavior if you do `first(anything)`, even if `anything` isn't a column name)

Comment: Very interesting problem. Seems like a bug from dbplyr; you might want to refactor this like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/4738478

Comment: I've reported the bug [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/129). Note that it can be basically reproduced (if you have the Lahman package installed) with `tbl(dbplyr::lahman_sqlite(), "Batting") %>% summarize(first(G))`